# original_transaction_id is not coming while validating Apple receipt after Successful IAP

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

I have Auto-renewable IAP plan in my App, which user has to purchase to listen full song. The issue has occurred moments after the user has made the in-app purchase and the app has been notified as to the successful transaction, then the appStoreReceipt in the app is validated.

I have base64 encoded string(that I can share in personal) and I am adding response after I verified the receipt, Also I have included master shared secret and app specific shared secret.

I also raised a bug on Apple feedback assistance, but they are not replying me since last week.

I hope anyone can help me out with this.

```
This is the response after validation of receipt:

<pre>ReceiptValidator\iTunes\ProductionResponse Object
(
    [result_code:protected] => 0
    [bundle_id:protected] => com.allaccess
    [app_item_id:protected] => 1479910471
    [original_purchase_date:protected] => Carbon\Carbon Object
        (
            [date] => 2020-06-04 17:28:14.000000
            [timezone_type] => 1
            [timezone] => +00:00
        )

    [request_date:protected] => Carbon\Carbon Object
        (
            [date] => 2020-08-25 15:40:51.000000
            [timezone_type] => 1
            [timezone] => +00:00
        )

    [receipt_creation_date:protected] => Carbon\Carbon Object
        (
            [date] => 2020-06-04 17:28:14.000000
            [timezone_type] => 1
            [timezone] => +00:00
        )

    [receipt:protected] => Array
        (
            [receipt_type] => Production
            [adam_id] => 1479910471
            [app_item_id] => 1479910471
            [bundle_id] => com.allaccess
            [application_version] => 1.0.1
            [download_id] => 28071597429667
            [version_external_identifier] => 836208084
            [receipt_creation_date] => 2020-06-04 17:28:14 Etc/GMT
            [receipt_creation_date_ms] => 1591291694000
            [receipt_creation_date_pst] => 2020-06-04 10:28:14 America/Los_Angeles
            [request_date] => 2020-08-25 15:40:50 Etc/GMT
            [request_date_ms] => 1598370050555
            [request_date_pst] => 2020-08-25 08:40:50 America/Los_Angeles
            [original_purchase_date] => 2020-06-04 17:28:14 Etc/GMT
            [original_purchase_date_ms] => 1591291694000
            [original_purchase_date_pst] => 2020-06-04 10:28:14 America/Los_Angeles
            [original_application_version] => 1.0.1
            [in_app] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [latest_receipt:protected] => 
    [latest_receipt_info:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [purchases:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [pending_renewal_info:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [raw_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [receipt] => Array
                (
                    [receipt_type] => Production
                    [adam_id] => 1479910471
                    [app_item_id] => 1479910471
                    [bundle_id] => com.allaccess
                    [application_version] => 1.0.1
                    [download_id] => 28071597429667
                    [version_external_identifier] => 836208084
                    [receipt_creation_date] => 2020-06-04 17:28:14 Etc/GMT
                    [receipt_creation_date_ms] => 1591291694000
                    [receipt_creation_date_pst] => 2020-06-04 10:28:14 America/Los_Angeles
                    [request_date] => 2020-08-25 15:40:50 Etc/GMT
                    [request_date_ms] => 1598370050555
                    [request_date_pst] => 2020-08-25 08:40:50 America/Los_Angeles
                    [original_purchase_date] => 2020-06-04 17:28:14 Etc/GMT
                    [original_purchase_date_ms] => 1591291694000
                    [original_purchase_date_pst] => 2020-06-04 10:28:14 America/Los_Angeles
                    [original_application_version] => 1.0.1
                    [in_app] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [status] => 0
            [environment] => Production
        )

    [is_retryable:protected] => 
)
```

Here, there is no original_transaction_id. I am facing this issue since last month.

Thank you